# unable to write jarlist cache file Facebook SDK on Android

Tags: android, integration, facebook-sdk-3.0

i am trying to integrate facebook login to my android application. according to [Facebook Help](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)
i tried to implement, while i am importing facebook sdk to eclipse the below error showing, not understood what happen.

even i installed Android Verion 2.2 (API 8). also bot no use, same error showing.

My Console Errors

```
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - ProfilePictureSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/ProfilePictureSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - BooleanOGSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/BooleanOGSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - GraphApiSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/GraphApiSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - Scrumptious] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/Scrumptious/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - PlacePickerSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/PlacePickerSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - SessionLoginSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/SessionLoginSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - FriendPickerSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/FriendPickerSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - HelloFacebookSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/HelloFacebookSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:08 - SwitchUserSample] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/SwitchUserSample/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:09 - FacebookSDK] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/FacebookSDK/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:09 - FacebookSDK] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/FacebookSDK/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:09 - FacebookSDK] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/FacebookSDK/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:09 - FacebookSDK] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/FacebookSDK/bin/jarlist.cache
[2013-07-25 10:15:09 - Hackbook] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/devendar/workspace/Hackbook/bin/jarlist.cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook sdk does not support API 8.
Select the project, click on Project>Properties > Android and choose a lower API.
If an error persists, try Project >Properties > Clean.

Comment: What? This is an outrageous answer! From the dev site: You'll need to have the Android 2.2 (API 8) components installed in order to use the Facebook SDK. Second, choose a lower API? If he chooses a lower API what will be different???

Answer (score 0):

Check the file owner of every /workspace/%ComponentName%/bin/

If it is belongs to someone not you - try 'chown' terminal command & change the owner to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem as you... here what i did:

I notice when i cloned the facebook sdk from github the "libs" folder and files(bolts.jar and android-support-v4.jar) were missing. So i created a new folder named libs and i copied the missing jars inside it.

To get the missing jars i downloaded the sdk from facebook developers website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

hope it helps